# Distance function-inequality in unit sphere

Tags: euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-inequalities

Assume that $d$ is a distance function (i.e. Riemannian metric) on a unit sphere $X$ of Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}^3$ (That is, $d$ is an angle between two unit vectors). If $e_i$ is an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{E}^3$, i.e. $d(e_i,e_j)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $i\neq j$, then prove that

> $$ \sum_{i=1}^3 \
> \bigg|\pi - d(e_i,u)-d(e_i,v) \bigg| \geq \pi - d(u,v)
> $$

**Proof :** When $f(x)=\bigg|\pi - T(x)\bigg|$ and $T(x)=d(x,u)+d(x,v)$, then $T$ is a 2-Lipschitz function. And $f(x)=f(-x)$.

Comment: What's $S^2(1)$?

Comment: It is a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $d$ is intrinsic metric on it.

Comment: Are u,v generic vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @big-lion : I edited.